# Peirce's law, law of the excluded middle, and intuitionism.

Tags: logic, peirce

I have no training in formal logic and have tried to understand how Peirce's law is equivalent to the law of the excluded middle to no avail. I hope someone can explain this to me.

Also, in passing, I wanted to know why intuitionistic logic rejects the law of the excluded middle?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can see the proof [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Peirce%27s_Law_Equivalent_to_Law_of_Excluded_Middle)

Comment: This is Peirce's original explanation : "That it is true appears as follows. It can only be false by the final consequent x being false while its antecedent (x−><y)−>x is true. If this is true, either its consequent x is true, when the whole formula would be true, or its antecedent x−>y is false. But in the last case the antecedent of x−>y, that is x, must be true."

Comment: For the rejection of LEM by intuitionists, see the ansewr to this [post](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/10055/what-are-the-truth-values-of-intuitionistic-logic)

Comment: Thus, being equivalent to LEM, [Intuitionistic logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/) rejects also Peirce's law.

Answer (score 5):

For the first part :

> (P ∨ ¬ P) ⊢ [((P→Q)→P)→P]

we can prove it using the following *axiom system* for (propositional) [Intuitionistic logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/) and *modus ponens*.

*Proof*

1) P --- assumed

2) ((P→Q)→P)→P --- from axiom **A → (B → A)**, with P in place of **A** and ((P→Q)→P) as **B**, and 1), by *modus ponens*

3) P → [((P→Q)→P)→P] --- from 1) and 2) by *Deduction Theorem* (or →-introduction in *Natural Deduction*), "discharging" assumption 1)

4) ¬P --- assumed

5) (P→Q) --- from axiom **¬A → (A → B)** (*ex falso quodlibet*) and 4), by *modus ponens*

6) (P→Q)→P --- assumed

7) P --- from 5) and 6), by *modus ponens*

8) ((P→Q)→P)→P --- from 6) and 7), by *Deduction Theorem*, "discharging" assumption 6)

9) ¬P → [((P→Q)→P)→P] --- from 4) and 8) by *Deduction Theorem*, "discharging" assumption 4)

Now that we have derived : P → [((P→Q)→P)→P] (3) and ¬P → [((P→Q)→P)→P] (9), we use the axiom **(A → C) → ((B → C) → (A ∨ B → C))** with P in place of **A**, ¬P in place of **B** and ((P→Q)→P)→P as **C** to derive, by *modus ponens* twice :

> > 10) (P ∨ ¬ P) → [((P→Q)→P)→P].

---

For the other part, we can prove :

> if ⊢ [((P→Q)→P)→P], then ⊢ (P ∨ ¬ P)

using two additonal laws, which are intuitionistically valid :

- ⊢ ¬(P ∨ ¬ P) ↔ (¬P ∧ ¬¬ P) --- for the intuitionistically valid De Morgan's laws, see [Intuitionistic  logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic)

and :

- ⊢ ¬¬(P ∨ ¬ P).

*Proof of* : ¬¬(P ∨ ¬ P)

1) ¬(P ∨ ¬ P) --- assumed

2) (¬P ∧ ¬¬ P) --- from 1) by De Morgan (see above)

3) ¬P --- from 2) and axiom **A & B → A**, by *modus ponens

4) ¬¬ P --- from 3) and axiom **A & B → B**, by *modus ponens

5) ¬(P ∨ ¬ P) → ¬P --- from 1) and 3) by *Deduction Theorem*

6) ¬(P ∨ ¬ P) → ¬¬P --- from 1) and 4) by *Deduction Theorem*

7) ¬¬(P ∨ ¬ P) --- from 5) and 6) and axiom **(A → B) → ((A → ¬B) → ¬A)**, by *modus ponens* twice.

Now for the main *Proof*, where we use the *falsum* ⊥ and define *negation* through the abbreviation : ¬P for P → ⊥.

1) (P ∨ ¬ P) → ⊥ --- assumed

2) ¬(P ∨ ¬ P) --- from 1) and the abbreviation above

3) ¬¬(P ∨ ¬ P) --- we have proved it above

4) (P ∨ ¬ P) --- from 3) and 2) and the axiom : **¬A → (A → B)**, by *modus ponens* twice

5) ((P ∨ ¬ P) → ⊥) → (P ∨ ¬ P) --- from 1) and 4) by *Deduction Theorem*

6) [((P ∨ ¬ P) → ⊥) → (P ∨ ¬ P)] → (P ∨ ¬ P) --- from Peirce's law : **((A→B)→A)→A** with (P ∨ ¬ P) as **A** and ⊥ as **B**

> > 7) (P ∨ ¬ P) --- from 5) and 6) by *modus ponens*.

---

*Comment*

We can summarize the situation as follows.

In *classical* logic we have : ⊢((P→Q)→P)→P and : ⊢ P ∨ ¬ P , because both are *tautologies*.

Also :

> ⊢ (P ∨ ¬ P) <-> [((P→Q)→P)→P]

is a *valid* logical law.

In *intuitionistic* logic we have that : ⊢ [((P→Q)→P)→P] iff ⊢ (P ∨ ¬ P), and also ⊢(P ∨ ¬ P) → [((P→Q)→P)→P].

But **not** ⊢ [((P→Q)→P)→P] → (P ∨ ¬ P).

Answer (score 2):

You have two questions here, which don't really relate to each other. It may be worth asking two seperate ones. I'll answer the first here.

Pierces law states: ((p implies q) implies p) implies p

This is equivalent to the law of the excluded middle in propositional logic. One can prove this by using truth tables (a la Wittgenstein).

First observes the truth table for [material implication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_implication):

> 1. (T implies T) is T
> 2. (T implies F) is F
> 3. (F implies T) is T
> 4. (F implies F) is T

1. suppose p=T and q=T

> - ((T implies T) implies T) implies T
> - T

2. suppose p=T and q=F

> - ((T implies F) implies T) implies T
> - (F implies T) implies T
> - T implies T
> - T

3. suppose p=F and q=T

> - ((F implies T) implies F) implies F
> - (T implies F) implies F
> - F implies T
> - T

4. suppose p=F and q=F

> - ((F implies F) implies F) implies F
> - (T implies F) implies F
> - F implies T
> - T

Since the expression always simplifies to true for any assignment of truth value to the propositions p and q; we must have that the entire expression is always true; that is it is a tautology.

An alternative proof could use the equivalence of (p implies q) with (not p or q) and use the de Morgan laws to simplify.

Comment: But why is saying that it is a tautology make it equivalent to LEM?

Comment: @David - in classical logic every two tautologies are (trivially) equivalent (they are always eveluated to T by truth-table). The interesting issue is to prove their equivalence in *intuitionistic* logic, where the concept of tautology does not apply, and thus the truth-table algorithm doesn not work ...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: There is another interesting perspective on this which is that we've reduced LEM to a proposition involving only implication; hence we can examine a fragment of logic involving only implication. Does this lead anywhere - I don't know; but it bears examining; and probably has been.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: I didn't know that truth-tables failed in intuitionistic logic; why is that - and should I ask a separate question?

Comment: @MoziburUllah - what I mean is that truth-table "incorporate" classical semantics; in intuitionsitic logic **not** all tautologies are valid (see LEM). Thus, we cannot use them to prove an intuitionistically valid law.